# Aggregate Functions in Automation script in Maximo 7.6.1

Tags: maximo

I came across a documentation to use aggregate functions and tried using the same to determine the MAX value however Maximo gives me an error message as

```
MAXF("cxvalue","value","startdate",DURATION(0,0,7,0,0,0))
 cxvalue is the relationship name 
 value - attributename 
 startdate  - date parameter 

NameError: name 'MAXF' is not defined in <script> at line number 1
```

Below is the URL that I had referred 
[Maximo Formula](https://community.ibm.com/HigherLogic/System/DownloadDocumentFile.ashx?DocumentFileKey=6bc4a5cb-4968-134e-1171-1d12e48b7862&forceDialog=0)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Python automation scripting error?

Because it looks like you're using a built-in formula keyword (MAXF) in an automation script. You can create a custom formula with the automation script framework but I don't think you can refer to formula functions that way in your automation scripts, hence the error you're getting.

You can create formulas within the Database Configuration application:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mbs.doc/configur/r_form_operators_functions.html

You can refer to these 2 IBM PDFs for more details on the Formulas framework:

[Doc #1](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/02db2a84-fc66-4667-b760-54e495526ec1/page/03ad118c-6040-43dd-bc6d-d7a03510d135/attachment/1e99c7b4-1c32-4fca-a45c-e8e3becae30b/media/MaximoFormula%20%282%29.pdf)

[Doc #2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/02db2a84-fc66-4667-b760-54e495526ec1/page/03ad118c-6040-43dd-bc6d-d7a03510d135/attachment/37c2dd71-2dab-4371-a7b6-782fda617bf4/media/MaximoFormulasV2%20%281%29.pdf)